# Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources'.

Tags: react-native

i am running sample application. When i generate apk for android getting error like this......

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources'.
    > Failed to process resources, see aapt output above for details.

    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

    * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

    BUILD FAILED in 59s
    39 actionable tasks: 36 executed, 3 up-to-date
```

Please give me any suggestion for this. Thank you.

Comment: i am not able to generate the issue in fresh install, so you can try some of solution from "https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/5787", hope this will help you.

Comment: Hi, @prince thank you for your response........ but this link github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/5787 displays page not found error.

Comment: actually the above link has an extra " that gives the error.
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/5787

Answer (score 0):

In my case helps:

```
react-native link

react-native run-android --variant=release
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to delete both ios,android and node module folder. Run the following commands

```
1)  npm install //to get the node module folder

2) react-native upgrade //to get android and ios folder

3) react-native link // for linking the libraries

3) react-native run-ios/android
```